# Data extension values in the "Update Contact" activity in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I'm looking for a way to use fields from a data extension (that is the entry source for a journey) in the "Update Contact" activity.

I want to create a sort of log in a different data extension. Let's say I have a `sourceDE`that is used by the journey and a `journeylogDE` where I would like to write the `email` of contact that's currently in the journey.

What should I write in the value field to get a value from the currently used record in the `sourceDE`?

I tried `{{Contact.Attribute.sourceDE.email}}`, but it did not return any values.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any tips how to fix this issue.

Comment: That data binding looks like it should work. Have you linked the data extension in the data designer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same question and finally came to a solution.

To access the attributes of the source DE you should use the following syntax : 
{{Event."DEAudience-8f8575fe-2e87-d24b-3e7b-e82f4320ff24"."Email"}}

To find the right id you should go on your JB with chrome, open the inspector and in the source code you can find it (just search "DEAudience"): [image]

You can now use any attribute from your source DE.

NB: If you change the source DE the DEAudience id will also change.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Looks like this method doesn't work any longer. It certainly used to work.

Comment: It worked for me today. Note that the DEAudience ID found with the inspector is not the EXTERNAL KEY of the DE.

Comment: Is it possible in the UpdateContact, to retrieve a field from a Salesforce object?
For Instance, I have a creation of task, then I have my Update Activity where I would like to retrieve the Id of the task or another field that I don't have in entry source.

Comment: @MahmoudGueye, you should be able to do that by using this model: {{Interaction.[ActivityCustomerKey].[OutArgumentName]}}. According to the docs the ActivityCustomerKey is journey-unique key for the activity and the OutArgumentName is specified by that activity. For example, I create a lead with a lead activity. To grab that lead ID value I'd use: {{Interaction.SALESCLOUDACTIVITY-2.salesforceObjectID}}. That SALESCLOUDACTIVITY-2 is the assigned AcitvityCustomerKey and could change per journey. Easy way to find that is to drop in a new activity after the task creation - look there for the name.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, so valuable. Had to get the right grip, but now it's working for me, and it's really a great alternative for progressive profiling if not having other options. Good stuff

Comment: If you cannot find the right value, instead of searching for DEAudience, in the Developer Console run: 

document.querySelector('div[data-region="entry-source-options"] ul li[data-selected="true"]').getAttribute('data-value');

Answer (score 7):

As I can see, the easiest way to find the right value to fill that fields in Update Contact Data is to start configuring some entry creation in Salesforce. For example, "create" Task activity.
[image]