# Marketing Cloud Journey Data Not Available for Exit Criteria?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, criteria-filter, data-designer

Why can't I define journey exit criteria using attributes from **journey data**, instead of only attributes from **contact data**, which seem to be all that's available?

I ask because I need to use the attribute comparison feature, as shown here...

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5

...in the exit criteria definition, to match up the ID of the record that is **in the journey** with the same ID of the record that is **in a master DE** (which has an attribute group in Data Designer), in order to only remove subscribers from the journey based only on that specific record (our subscribers and our records have a one-to-many relationship).

I see that journey data is available for **decision split** criteria. So why not extend its availability into **exit** criteria as well?

1. Using decision splits to substitute for exit criteria is a
   relatively prohibitive method in this case, as the journey is
   already very complex, and so are the necessary exit criteria.
2. Creating a new attribute group in Data Designer for every journey
   entry DE is also a relatively prohibitive method in this case (and
   extremely duplicative) because we have hundreds of journeys, and
   every journey's DE has the exact same list of attributes.

I have read these below and am still not reaching the precise answer:

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_define_exit_criteria.htm&type=5
- [Journey Exit Criteria Based on SF Custom Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257231/journey-exit-criteria-based-on-sf-custom-object)

Answer (score 1):

As for the question of "*why*" is only something that someone from SFMC Product Development team can answer to.

Point is that this is not possible at the moment, although there are some requests posted to Idea Portal, so you're definitely not alone with this requirement.
All we can do right now is just **vote** for the ideas and make some noise to our SFMC account executives.

- [Journey Data in Exist Critieria and Goals](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PZFHQA4)
- [Journey Builder Goal and Exit Criteria Options](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003X5EQAU)

Answer (score 0):

I am not from SFMC Product Development, but maybe I can answer why. I had a different problem/question: contacts for which a certain 'No mail' flag is raised, must exit the journey. So that is an exit criteria.

However, the Data Extension that feeds my journey also screens for that flag, because it does not make sense to have all contacts enter the journey, and to immediately remove a lot of them that have the 'No mail' flag raised, using the exit criteria.

So: only contacts that do not have the 'No mail' flag raised enter the journey. Contacts for which this flag is raised during the journey, must exit it.

But if an exit criteria uses journey data, how is this going to work? Because only contacts that do not have the 'No mail' flag raised are in the Data Extension, only they will be updated. So if exit criteria use journey data, the exit criteria would never be satisfied, because those contacts will never be visible or updated.

The way it is now, namely that exit criteria uses a master DE and not journey data, ensures that the above scenario works.

It is a bit complicated, I hope you understand.