# Insert Contact Key in Data Extension from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We want to insert Contact Key using Journey Builder Update contact activity in a new DE ( Not Entry Source DE)
Is it possible to insert contact key using update contact activity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default the values put into the data extension are hard-coded and you need a workaround to get dynamic values that are different for each customer.

You can find the easiest way of achieving this [here in the answer of @jogsottot](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247678/39888) (basically pretend you want to configure a SF object and just copy the string containing Journey Data into the Update Contact activity)

Comment: I tried this approch , however its not working , Journey doesnot insert the ContactKey.Any other setting is required?

Comment: @SushantEdlabadkar what is being inserted when you run the journey? Is it empty or is the string you pasted in, inserted into the DE?

Comment: DE remains Empty., Also Contact doesnot move to subsequnet step some error seems to be coming internally.