# Remove subscribers from a journey data extension via an action in the journey itself

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

Please help me sort this issue.

Subscribers from 70 different countries are injected into a journey data extension via API originating from our Axapta ERP.
I can't control what is injected via Axapta.
Of the subscribers injected only those from 3 of the 70 countries qualify for emails in the journey, the rest are exited from the journey again after 1 minute.
Of the subscribers injected from those 3 countries qualifying, only approx. 50% actually qualify for emails in the journey, the rest are also exited from the journey again after 1 minute.

Can I in any way remove those subscribers exiting the journey after 1 minute from the journey data extension via any action in the journey itself?
(exit criteria or a journey builder activity)

I want to do so, so the journey data extension only reflects those actually on the journey for exclusion purposes.

Thank you

Note: *I could probably accomplish this by querying the journey exclusion data extension into a new data extension using the same logic for the decisions splits as in the journey, but I'd have to maintain the logic twice, and the query part would be a little out of reach for my customer*

Comment: Whats the schedule of the journey? Maybe you could trigger an Automation with an API request and the journey listens to the trigger of the journey you triggered. This way you could use an SQL activity to filter only the valid contacts into the dataextension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions:

1. Create a filter on the API entry event
2. Use the Update Contact block in the Journey to log in a separate data extension (for your exclusion purposes) who qualified for emails in this journey. Just remember that you need to work around the limitations of this block to dynamically log the values for each customer - I would recommend [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247678/39888) and that you can only log data to 5 columns this way.
3. Manually add a Boolean field to the data extension, use the Update Contact block to write True or False to this field. Then you can either create a new filtered data extension, query based on this DE or have a script delete all records within this DE with a particular value.

Comment: Thank you. Used the 3rd approach. Extremely easy to set up and very handy. Good knowledge!